# Microservices and reports in a serverless application

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, microservices, serverless-framework, serverless

We are using microservices (API gateway, Lamba, dynamo). Each microservice has its own database that is not directly touched by another microservice.

We are looking to introduce a Reporting microservice that will be called when customers request reports. The reports will be generated based on data from databases of multiple other microservices.

As DynamoDB is not great with aggregates,

1. How should these reports be generated and stored?
2. How should reporting microservice access this data from other DB's that are owned by different microservices?